# Inject attribute from association table into the associated record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have the following model in my Rails app:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, class_name: 'User'
end
```

While `course.members` successfully returns the course's members, I don't get access to the `Membership` model which has a `role` attribute.

How do I find the user role without having to find the `Membership` given my `Course` and `User`? Can I inject the `role` attribute to `User` somehow in the context association?

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :memberships
end
```

Comment: how does the member model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, not the most beautiful and idiomatic though

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships

  def members
    User.joins(:memberships).where(id: memberships.ids).select('users.*, memberships.role')
  end
end
```

A better approach, suggested through the comments:

```
has_many :members, -> { select('users.*, memberships.role') }, class_name: 'User', through: :memberships, source: :user
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept your answer because you led me to the better solution. I can do `has_many :members, -> { select('users.*, memberships.role') }, class_name: 'User', through: :memberships, source: :user` and Rails will take care of the rest. Could you please update your answer with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and couldn't find any way to fetch the intermediate association without explicitly finding it. It's not that ugly, though:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :memberships

  def role_in(course)
    memberships.find_by!(course: course).role
  end
end

user.role_in(course)
# => "teacher"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamically storing the contextual `role` depending on what `Course` is used is not a good idea. It feels hacky to me because the attribute value becomes set implicitly rather than by explicit execution. A `User` would appear different depending on where and how it's instantiated, despite representing a row in the database.

I would instead implement something like below:

```
class User
  def course_role(course)
    memberships.find_by_course(course).role
  end
end

class Course
  def user_role(user)
    members.find_by_user(user).role
  end
end
```

This way, it's explicit that calling methods on either the `User` or `Course` to get the role depends on the respective memberships they are associated with.

Comment: This is also spaghetti to my tastes.

Comment: I'm sorry if you felt offended - I replaced that description with a quantifiable explanation.

Comment: Oh, I'm not offended. This is what you usually do when you have to handle this up -- it feels spaghetti to me because while `has_many :through` helps me finding the associated user, I lose metadata which resides in `Membership`. I don't think it's necessarily wrong to have injected behaviour -- we have decorators for using models in view which are pretty awesome -- association decorators could work my use case.